# AWS ECS upload file to bucket from within container via bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I have a ecs task running with aws fargate. I generate some files on the container and need to upload these files to an s3 bucket.

Can I do this by installing the aws cli to the container?

I'm not sure about the following stuff:

- Do I need to use some rest api (like python boto3 library) or can I use the aws console?
- How should I authenticate the requests (iam and aws secrets manager?)

Comment: How did you automate it? Reckon when you generate the files, it takes time. And after the files have been generated, you upload them to S3. How did you detect the files have been generated and how did you execute the `aws-cli` to upload the files into S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to use some rest api (like python boto3 library) or can I
> use the aws console?

Are you asking how to install the AWS CLI into the Docker container running in ECS? You would need to update your Docker image to include the AWS CLI and then redeploy the container to ECS. The AWS API, Boto3, or the AWS console are not going to help with that task.

> How should I authenticate the requests (iam and aws secrets manager?)

By assigning an IAM role to the ECS task.

Comment: But do I have to run aws configure - or will the aws cli commands work without importing any secrets into the container?

Comment: The AWS CLI tool will automatically detect and utilize the IAM role associated with the ECS Task. There is no need to configure it.

Comment: It worked - I used a bucket name which already has been used so I got a permission denied exception. This partly caused the confusion - glad you helped :)